# Laravel different joins based on where

Tags: php, laravel

So basically what I' trying to do is grab all the friends to a given user, but not grab the given user itself, only the friends. But I got stuck when I needed to have different joins, based on where's. Example:

If the given user is equal to `user_id_sender`, I would like join tables on `user_id_receiver`. And the other way around.
I came up with this:

```
DB::table('friends') -> where('friends.user_id_sender', $user_id)
        -> orWhere('friends.user_id_receiver', $user_id)
        -> join('profiles as profile_receiver', 'profile_receiver.user_id', '=', 'friends.user_id_sender')
        -> join('profiles as profile_sender', 'profile_sender.user_id', '=', 'friends.user_id_receiver')
        -> join('users as receiver', 'receiver.id', '=', 'friends.user_id_sender')
        -> join('users as sender', 'sender.id', '=', 'friends.user_id_receiver')
        -> select('receiver.name', 'receiver.id', 'profile_receiver.picture', 'sender.name', 'sender.id', 'profile_sender.picture', 'sender.last_seen', 'receiver.last_seen')
        -> get();
```

I have only 2 users currently (admin, and user). If I try to view the friends of admin, I see admin (and that is not right, i would like to see user on admin friends and admin on user friends).

I have also tried to use joins inside where clauses, but I found out that doesn't work. I Could do two queries like so, but I would like 1 query only:

```
$friends1 = DB::table('friends') -> where('friends.user_id_sender', $user_id)
        -> join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'friends.user_id_receiver')
        -> join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends.user_id_receiver')
        -> select('users.name', 'profiles.picture', 'users.id')
        -> get();

    $friends2 = DB::table('friends') -> where('friends.user_id_receiver', $user_id)
        -> join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'friends.user_id_sender')
        -> join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends.user_id_sender')
        -> select('users.name', 'profiles.picture', 'users.id')
        -> get();
```

How would I do this?

My database table that contains all the friendships looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: please post with full error messages

Comment: Oh, its not any error messages. It works for the one user, but not for the other one.

I can see admin as friends, on both admin and user. And I'm supposed to see admin as friend on the user, and user as friend on admin. It doesn't work both ways kind of. I get the same result if the `$user_id` is either 1 or 2.

Comment: your code is too messy just put ur database table along with foreign key and let me solve

Comment: Users table: http://i.imgur.com/P1RII4e.png
Profiles table: http://i.imgur.com/zzEm9Ql.png
Friends table: http://i.imgur.com/z2nUm8y.png

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two ways this could me done that is whenever someone accepts the friend request posting two rows that it once `user_sender_id = friend` and `user_id_receiver = you`  and next `time user_sender_id = you` and `user_id_receiver =  ur friend` and  next is having two queries.